# What is the difference between 'declarations of interest' and 'disclosure statement'

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, publishers, conflict-of-interest

In a journal application, there are two fields need to be filled but I can not tell what is the difference between the two:

```
Declarations of interest
Disclosure statement
```

Is there anyone of them where I can write the Acknowledgement for the funding body?
I looked at some published papers for the same journal trying to see some examples. I found one journal have this in the Disclosure statament:

> No potential conflict of interest was reported by the author(s).

Now, where should I report conflict of interest? Where should I add the acknowledgement?

Comment: I'm surprised if they don't explain it somewhere on a web site, say. Or ask the editor for guidance.